# Is there more than one backward induction outcome for the pirate game?

Tags: game-theory

Lets consider a 'smaller' variant of the pirate game (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirate_game):

There are three pirates with a chest of 100 gold coins. They now have to decide how to split the coins.

The pirate world's rules of distribution say that the most senior pirate first proposes a plan of distribution. The pirates, including the proposer, then vote on whether to accept this distribution. If the majority (including the proposer) accepts the plan, the coins are dispersed and the game ends. In case of a tie vote, the proposer has the casting vote. If the majority rejects the plan, the proposer is thrown overboard from the pirate ship and dies, and the process repeats with next most senior pirate making a new proposal to begin the distribution again.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Is there more than one (even two) bckward induction outcome for this game? As of now, I only have the outcome: $(99,0,1)$ from backward induction. Some help and insight will be great!

$\textbf{Edit/Addition:}$

Are the outcomes $(99,1,0)$ and $(0,100,0)$ possible as well by backward induction? If someone can illustrate this via a game tree that wil be great, as I am really clueless on this.

Comment: I don't get it -- don't you just look at the 5 person variant, and then stop when you're at the third step?

Comment: @MCT I apologize for the confusion, but here I am looking at a smaller version of the game out of curiosity. In particular, I will like to find out if other outcomes such as $(99,1,0)$ and $(0,100,0)$ are possible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another outcome: $X=(100,0,0)$.

Let A, B, C denote the three pirates with descending seniority.

Here, C does not have a strict incentive to vote for $X$, but he doesn't have a strict incentive to vote against it either. He gets $0$ by voting either way. So voting *for* $X$ is also rational. Therefore $X$ is also an outcome of backward induction.

Comment: I think normally one takes the assumption that pirates *prefer* to throw people overboard if all else are equal, in which case this is impossible. This is indeed the assumption given in the wikipedia article.

Comment: @MCT: The assumption is not explicitly stated in OP's post. Also, if you consider the fact that it is a weakly dominant strategy for C to vote *for* A's proposal, regardless of what the proposal is, then outcome $X$ would not appear that unreasonable after all.

Comment: @HerrK. Going along with your reasoning above, are $(99,1,0)$ and $(0,100,0)$ possible outcomes as well? And also, can we instead find the game's sub-game perfect outcomes, which are also backward induction outcomes as this game is a game with perfect information?

Comment: @Stoner: Those two cannot be subgame perfect because, conditional on C voting for both proposals, A can do better by shifting more coins from B to himself and be strictly better off.

Comment: Ah alright I see it. In that case, am I right to say that your answer $(100,0,0)$ is subgame perfect? Also, am I correct to say that we have 2 backward induction outcomes partitioned from the outcome $(99,0,1)$: $(A,R,A)$ and $(A,A,A)$, where $A$ denotes accepting the proposal, and $R$ denotes rejecting the proposal? Here, we assume that the first pirate (proposal) always accepts his own proposal.

Comment: @Stoner: Yes, those are the two outcomes that can be achieved in two different subgame perfect equilibria. But you have to be more careful in describing what those equilibria are. Strategies in the equilibria consist of a proposal (when it's one's turn to make one) as well as a voting decision on the each possible proposal by each person. So the description of the SPEs will have to be quite extensive.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the clarifications! As a final remark, for the context of the question I've posted above, is he answer of 2 backward induction (BI) outcomes: $(A,A,A)$ and $(A,R,A)$, where there are 2 subgame perfect outcomes $(99,0,1)$ and $(100,0,0)$ with the BI outcomes $\{ (A,A,A),(A,R,A)\}$ a right way to put it? :)

Comment: @Stoner: I'd say that (99,0,1) and (100,0,0) are the two outcomes consistent with backward induction. Note that backward induction is a method of determining [subgame perfect equilibria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgame_perfect_equilibrium) in finite games. For instance, an SPE leading to outcome (100,0,0) is the following: A proposes (100,0,0) and votes for his own proposal; B rejects any proposal by A, and proposes and votes for (0,100,0) when it's his turn to do so; C votes for all proposals from A and rejects all proposals from B.

Comment: @HerrK. Thanks again for the clarifications! It makes more sense to me now.